# What is the use of ATOM returned by RegisterClassEx function?

Tags: c, winapi, system-calls, systems-programming

I was reading the documentation of [RegisterClassEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and found that the return type of the function is `ATOM`.

```
ATOM RegisterClassEx(CONST WNDCLASSEX *lpwcx);
```

While creating a window using `CreateWindowEx` we can either pass the classname or ATOM Class in lpClassName.

So is there any significance of passing ATOM over classname ? or is it just an alternate way?

Thanks.

Comment: The performance difference hasn't been relevant in *years*. A lot of stuff you'll find in the Windows API is cruft that hasn't mattered since Win16. Things get a lot easier if you know what you can ignore.

Comment: @Cody Gray `Things get a lot easier if you know what you can ignore.` I'll keep than in my mind. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ATOM` is an alias to a string, like an index to a system array of strings. In the context of window classes, it's an alias to the class name.

So, it's just a different way of doing the same thing, but in theory this is more efficient.

Where I think ATOMs make more sense to use is in `GetProp` / `SetProp`, where you may be looking up that string for every windows message processed. Maybe you can gain some performance by using an ATOM; anyway it's so easy to use that you might as well.

Interestingly, ATOMs tables are system-wide as well, so if two processes register a window class of the same name, they will receive the same ATOM value, even though the class info will be different.

Comment: I found that Microsoft article [What’s the atom returned by RegisterClass useful for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041011-00/?p=37603) provided some context for me. The last paragraph sums things up...

"In other words, window class atoms are an anachronism. Like replacement dialog box classes, it’s one of those generalities of the Win32 API that never really got off the ground, but which must be carried forward for backwards compatibility."

Answer (score 2):

Its just an alternate way. On Windows 3, where this API was introduced (if not Windows 2.x even) string compares were slow operations. The ATOM allowed the rather frequent creation of windows to go that much faster.